# Artisan doesn't generate create, store etc. in controller

Tags: php, sql, laravel

So I'm using laravel, and when creating a controller with artisan it creates it without the create, store etc. things.

It outputs this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
         //
}
```

Shouldn't it generate index/create/store etc? If not, how do I generate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Laravel 5.2 and before, you just [ran something like this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers):

```
php artisan make:controller TasksController
```

And that generated the stubs for you. You had to explicitly pass a `--plain` to opt out of the stubbed methods. [As of Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) and above, you need to add `--resource` in order for it to stub those methods and it defaults to the plain version:

```
php artisan make:controller TasksController --resource
```

Which will stub the resource methods for you. This was changed in this commit: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/8e6ac01b4a311ec4740ab2bced01fbdf6f1241c5

Comment: Well, it added this:

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return view('tasks.index');
    }
}

Still missing those functions ( create, store, etc )

Answer (score 0):

you should use `php artisan make:controller YourController --resource` as mentioned [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers)